# QGIS crashes when I load .sid layer

Tags: qgis, mac, mrsid

I am using QGIS 2.12 Lyon on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.

I load a topographic map raster layer which happens to be in MrSID format (36105B5C.sid is the file). Every time, this makes QGIS crash.

I have followed instructions here, but most of it is for Linux or Windows. I have the GDAL 1.11 from KyngChaos and also the MrSID plugin, and have installed Lizardtech's Unified SDK 9.5 as instructed. (Except I installed Unified SDK 10, I think, 'cause 9.5 was not available.)

Still I cannot load the .sid file because it crashes QGIS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for an old unsupported version of QGIS. Please check with a new version an leave a message to reopen if necessary.