# QGIS crashes when loading sid file, gdalinfo also produces error in terminal

Tags: qgis, gdal, mrsid

I have the same problem as this person [QGIS crashes when I load .sid layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227074/qgis-crashes-when-i-load-sid-layer) and I am running qgis v2.18 on mac os 10.12.4. I have gdal 1.11 and 2.1 installed and have also made sure to install the correct files in the libraries folders for mrsid (downloaded from lizard tech) per instructions on this site  http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks. Every time I try to add a sid file to qgis it crashes. when I try to run `gdalinfo` on the image in terminal I get this error:

`Segmentation fault: 11`

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: What version of the Lizardtech SDK did you install? Did you see the note on the [MrSID plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) - *(Additional requirement: Lizardtech's Unified SDK 9.5, see install instructions in plugin readme) [NOTE: Lizardtech only offers the latest SDK, which requires a complete rebuild of GDAL, which will happen at GDAL 2.2. The MrSID plugin will NOT work on new installs of the current GDAL unless you can find an old SDK.]*

Comment: yes I think that is the problem, and I don't know where to find an old SDK

Comment: GDAL 2.2 will be released next week.